# Empty where clause in Laravel 5.1 preferring eloquent method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, eloquent

i am looking to produce the following query in laravel 5.1 with eloquent method.

The mysql query is a follows

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE 1 = 1 ORDER BY o_date DESC LIMIT 25
```

No matter what i cant get the

```
WHERE 1 = 1
```

part working.

am new to laravel and pretty sure this is easy. but can't figure it out.

I have tried the following variations

```
$orders = orders::where('1', 1)->orderBy('o_date', 'desc')->take(25)->get();
$orders = orders::where(1)->orderBy('o_date', 'desc')->take(25)->get();
$orders = orders::where('1', '=', '1')->orderBy('o_date', 'desc')->take(25)->get();
```

but its not working. the query results is as shown below

```
> select count(*) as aggregate from `orders`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like (looking at 1=1) you need whereRaw

```
$orders = orders::whereRaw("any clause u wish")->orderBy('o_date', 'desc')->take(25)->get();
```

but if "any clause u wish" is not a VERY-VERY dinamical part u'd better look what else you can use

http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html

For the above example the below code works fine

```
$orders = orders::whereRaw("1 = 1")->orderBy('o_date', 'desc')->take(25)->get();
```

Answer (score -1):

Why do you want to create a condition that will be always true? I think that Eloquent is smart enought to remove this useless part of the query.

Comment: This is to work like a default query.... more conditions will be appended to it, once i implement the search options... and then i will like to dynamically append  more where conditions depending on the user input...

Comment: One good use is to have different conditions based on user rights, with some users able to see any/all rows.